# virtualenv "workon" doesn't work

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I made a virtualenv environment for a project. "workon projectname" worked and activated the environment but after I shut down my laptop it starts not working. Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to tell you what's wrong. You haven't even told us what OS you're using! Have you followed e.g. [this step](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment I'll simply attempt an answer as I think I know what the issue is.

Firstly, if you could provide more details as to what you mean by "not working" I will edit my answer if need be and attempt to help more.

Typically this happens because virtualenvwrapper is a shell script that needs to be sourced before you have access to commands like "workon" and "mkvirtualenv". My `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script is installed in `/usr/local/bin` so I simply run:

`$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Typically I add this line to my `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file to ensure these commands are always available in the shell. You can find more specific information for your setup in the [Installation Documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). Not having it sourced would definitely cause the commands to stop working after a shutdown.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! I ran the code "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" but it it gave me the below error. mkdir: /opt/virtual_env/: Permission denied       Also, I included the code in .bashrc and .profile. It seems that it didn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you may have created the virtualenv as another user or as root. Let me know if running the following command helps: `$ sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /opt/virtual_env`

Comment: Thanks again :) I ran the command but I got the error below. chown: youruser: illegal group name

Comment: You should replace *youruser* with your actual username, that was just a placeholder value I used.

Comment: Thanks again but I still get illegal group name.. Would you still have other ideas to fix?

Comment: You might just try `$ sudo chown -R youruser /opt/virtual_env`

Comment: Virtualenwrapper was working earlier for my case but yesterday I've made some additions to `.bashrc` file to get a project which required pyenv and saw the suspect immediately once I opened the file. `pyenv virtualenv-init` conflicts with this

Answer (score 2):

In my case I need to do the following steps (on Mac OS X 10.11):

I added this line:

```
source "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

to my `~/.bash_profile`

And afterwards, following Eric Scrivner instructions, I created a folder at /opt/ called virtual_env using `sudo mkdir /opt/virtual_env`

And finally, I run the command `sudo chown -R youruser /opt/virtual_env`

And than: `source ~/.bash_profile`