# How to call workon or deactivate virtualenvwrapper commands from a Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

My virtualenv works perfect from bash with:

```
$ workon mylovelyenv
// do something
$ deactivate
```

When I try to automate with makefile I can't get it right:

```
$ cat makefile
all:
    workon mylovelyenv           #doesn't work
    $(shell workon mylovelyenv)  #doesn't work either
    bash -c "workon mylovelyenv" #doesn't work either
    python go.py
    $(shell deactivate) # same here ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`make` out of the box runs each line in a recipe in a separate shell. That means that things like

```
all:
    cd there
    pwd
```

don't do what you might naïvely expect -- the `cd` happens in one shell instance, which then exits, then `pwd` runs in a new shell which starts back in the current working directory of the `make` process.

Similarly, `workon` and friends have to run in the same shell instance as subsequent commands which depend on it. In your case, probably

```
all:
    workon mylovelyenv; \
    python go.py
```

or (in GNU Make 3.82 or newer)

```
.ONESHELL:
all:
    workon mylovelyenv
    python go.py
```

There is no need to explicitly `deactivate` because that happens anyway when the subshell exits.

Comment: doesn't work for me - I get `/bin/sh: 3: workon: not found`, tried both ways, I have make `4.1` ... any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you are running `make` in a place where you don't have all the definitions which you have in your interactive shell. `workon` is really intended for interactive use anyway. If `virtualenvwrapper` (which I guess provides `workon`) works the same as the regular Python `virtualenv` you can use `mylovelyenv/bin/python` to run the virtualenv's Python as if you had activated the environment.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900090/virtualenv-workon-doesnt-work

Comment: Arrrrgggh ... I'll just wrap the makefile in a bash script ...